# Group the data from a list

Tags: python

I'm learning python now and I'm trying to group the data from a list

```
raw_list = [
    ['item3', [10, 10, 1]], 
    ['item4', [10, 10, 2]], 
    ['item7', [10, 10, 2]], 
    ['item8', [10, 10, 2]], 
    ['item2', [10, 10, 3]],
    ['item5', [10, 10, 4]],
    ['item1', [10, 10, 20]],
    ['item6', [10, 10, 20]],
    ['item9', [10, 10, 20]]
]
```

I'm trying to group by the third number in the nested list (1,2,3,4,20):

```
group = [
    [
        ['item3', [10, 10, 1]]
    ],
    [
        ['item4', [10, 10, 2]], 
        ['item7', [10, 10, 2]], 
        ['item8', [10, 10, 2]]
    ],
    [
        ['item2', [10, 10, 3]]
    ],
    [
        ['item5', [10, 10, 4]]
    ],
    [
        ['item1', [10, 10, 20]],
        ['item6', [10, 10, 20]],
        ['item9', [10, 10, 20]]
    ]
]
```

My code:

```
raw_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1][2])

group_list = list(i for i in itertools.groupby(raw_list, lambda x: x[1][2]))
print(group_list)
```

I think it's almost working, but I can't get the list of each group because it returns this:

```
[(1, <itertools._grouper object at 0x019AB7D8>), (2, <itertools._grouper object at 0x019B8430>), (3, <itertools._grouper object at 0x019B8730>), (4, <itertools._grouper object at 0x039E1F10>), (20, <itertools._grouper object at 0x039E1F70>)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close. `itertools.groupby` yields tuples of the form `(key, group)` where `group` is an iterator. If you convert the items from each `group` to a list you'll have what you want.

```
raw_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1][2])

# Notice the change in the list comprehension
group_list = [list(g) for _, g in itertools.groupby(raw_list, lambda x: x[1][2])]

print(group_list)
```

Which outputs the following list (which I then formatted)

```
[
    [
        ['item3', [10, 10, 1]]
    ],
    [
        ['item4', [10, 10, 2]],
        ['item7', [10, 10, 2]],
        ['item8', [10, 10, 2]]
    ],
    [
        ['item2', [10, 10, 3]]
    ],
    [
        ['item5', [10, 10, 4]]
    ],
    [
        ['item1', [10, 10, 20]],
        ['item6', [10, 10, 20]],
        ['item9', [10, 10, 20]]
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a list out of the grouper generator, not out of the pair (2-tuple).

```
group_list = [(i, list(grp)) 
    for i, grp in itertools.groupby(raw_list, lambda x: x[1][2]) ]
```

Output:

```
[(1, [['item3', [10, 10, 1]]]), 
 (2, [['item4', [10, 10, 2]], ['item7', [10, 10, 2]], ['item8', [10, 10, 2]]]),
 (3, [['item2', [10, 10, 3]]]),
 (4, [['item5', [10, 10, 4]]]), (20, [['item1', [10, 10, 20]], ['item6', [10, 10, 20]], ['item9', [10, 10, 20]]])]
```

Can you handle your list containment from there?